# How to Hide/show div acting on keyup filter input

Tags: jquery

I have a number of divs that are listed and I want to be able to add an input field that will allow a user to start typing and the divs are filtered accordinly

I'm trying the code below, but it's not filtering. It's not throwing up any errors either, so I'm not sure what to do at this point...

Here's the html markup:

```
<input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here...">


<ul id="equipdetails">
   <li>
      <div class="col-lg-8"><label data-equipid="3" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline exercise-txt"><input type="checkbox">Pega<span></span></label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
         <div class="exercise-img"></div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="col-lg-8"><label data-equipid="4" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline exercise-txt"><input type="checkbox">DOT NET<span></span></label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
         <div class="exercise-img"></div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="col-lg-8"><label data-equipid="5" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline exercise-txt"><input type="checkbox">Java<span></span></label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
         <div class="exercise-img"></div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="col-lg-8"><label data-equipid="6" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline exercise-txt"><input type="checkbox">JAVA Script<span></span></label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
         <div class="exercise-img"></div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="col-lg-8"><label data-equipid="26" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline exercise-txt"><input type="checkbox">Ruby On Rails<span></span></label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
         <div class="exercise-img"></div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="col-lg-8"><label data-equipid="27" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline exercise-txt"><input type="checkbox">NEW QSS<span></span></label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
         <div class="exercise-img"></div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**Here is JS Code**

```
$('#filter').keyup(function()
  {
          var val = $.trim(this.value).toUpperCase();
          $(".mt-checkbox").each(function()
          {
                  var parent = $(this).parent(),
                          length = $(this).text().length > 0;
                  if (length && $(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0)
                  {
                          parent.fadeOut("slow");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                          parent.show();
                  }
          });
  })
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/145/

Comment: What is `filter`?

Comment: <input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here...">

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the variable `val` to the search function, there is no variable defined as `filter`

```
$(this).text().search(new RegExp(val, "i")
```

*but is it possible to remove the dots also*, traverse up to `li` like instead of immediate parent

```
var parent = $(this).closest('li'),
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/cod7ceho/149/)

Comment: Thank you its working fine , but is it possible to remove the dots also ?

Comment: @UnKnown, Updated answer

Comment: yes working exactly as required thank you very much for your time sir .

Answer (score 0):

`filter` in your fiddle refers to the `input` with id `filter`

What you need in the value of the `input`

Change this

```
if (length && $(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0)
```

to

```
if (length && $(this).text().search(new RegExp($(filter).val(), "i"))
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf()` to search the value in the text like  `$(this).text().toUpperCase().trim().indexOf(val) < 0`

```
$('#filter').keyup(function()
  {

          var val = $.trim(this.value).toUpperCase();
          console.log(val);
          $(".mt-checkbox").each(function()
          {
                  var parent = $(this).parent(),
                          length = $(this).text().length > 0;

                  if (length && $(this).text().toUpperCase().trim().indexOf(val) < 0)
                  {
                          parent.fadeOut("slow");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                          parent.show();
                  }
          });
  })
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/152/)**

Other way is to use the same method you are using and replace the filter in your regex with val since your need to send the value in regex not the object itself

```
$(this).text().search(new RegExp(val, "i")) < 0)
```

Also you will want to remove the dots once your filte our for that fade out the `li` and to select that use `$(this).closest('li');`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/151/)

Both methods work, It depends which you want to use.